# How to create models using sequelize and typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have sequelize-cli installed globally.

When I run the command

```
sequelize model:create --name User --attributes name:string,email:string,password:string
```

it creates the model at `models/user.js` and migration at `migrations/20201115094126-create-user.js`

Both the files are created in Javascript. I want both the model and migration to be created in Typescript. In the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/typescript.html), I have only found the manual creation of models. Is there a way to create these files in Typescript?